What type of mount do i have?
Planning to buy a SRAM X.3 not sure what mount I have though. The model is a red and white Mongoose XR75 mtb.


Are you asking about a rear derailleur or front derailleur? No one knows off-hand the details of any particular bike. Post photos of your existing derailleur

You will need to give a little more detail in order to get an accurate answer. It is ok to use extra words to accurately describe what you are looking for. Currently this is an ambiguous question and the contributors here should not have to guess. So please, elaborate and give plenty of details in your question.

Going by search results, this is a 26" full-suspension bike sold by Walmart for around $200 in 2008.   "3x7 with shimano derailleur and SRAM shifters"   So I'd presume its Tourney.

A closer photo would confirm it, but the current photo (not by original poster) has something that looks a lot like claw mount. SRAM X.3 will does not have claw mount version so it won't fit and also would not work with the shifters.
